# Is Zend framework with backbone.js good idea?

Tags: php, zend-framework, backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js and I would like to create my first medium scale website application with backbone.js. I used to create websites only with zend framework. My question is: Is zend framework to heavy to use with backbone.js, with that I mean if I should rather use some other rest frameworks for php (Slim)? Or in other words, what is a good server side framework/library to use with php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use zend framework and backbone.js and the integration works pretty well.

Zend framework (ZF1) offers an abstract rest controller, which automatically handles GET/POST/DELETE/PUT requests. http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Rest/Zend_Rest_Controller.html

in our bootstrap, we set a module just for rest api controllers, called `api`. note your need to add a rest router for this module:

```
        $restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($frontController);
        $frontController->getRouter()->addRoute('oauth_route', $route, array('api')););
```

any controller in this module extends `Zend_Rest_Controller` and implements getAction, indexAction, deleteAction and so on.

PS. avoid `Zend_Rest_Server` & `Zend_Rest_Client`. these are old modules.

Comment: Did you have adapt the default sync method of backbone at all? So far I've found I need to set `Backbone.emulateJSON = true;` and `Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;` but it sends a json encoded string (e.g. `model={...`) in the POST. So I either need to adapt Zend or adapt sync so it seems, trying to find some working examples.

Answer (score 2):

[yiiframework](http://www.yiiframework.com/)is a good choice as a PHP framework.

Backbone.js is JavaScript MVC framework and all PHP frameworks including yiiframework are indeed PHP MVC frameworks, PHP has no conflict with Javascript. And yes of-course you can use backbone.js with any PHP framework.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/390/yiibackboneboilerplate-project-setup-for-your-yii-backbonejs-applications/

Comment: My question is not if I can, I know I can, I am asking if it is a good idea? Since zendframework isnt the lightest library.

Comment: If I am right the view component of Zend is not used at all if you use backbone?

Comment: why you think "it may be a bad idea"?

Comment: Because Zend wasnt made just for REST but offers a lot more... and since I think I will need just REST handling and Model of MVC It is more reasonable to use lighter library thats based on REST. Or am I wrong?

Comment: yiiframework is a good option.